# Can the Four Colour Theorem be proved using Albertson's Conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The Albertson's conjecture states that:

Among all graphs requiring $n$ colors, the complete graph $K_{n}$ is the one with the smallest crossing number. (I've taken the definition from Wikipedia)

I've been reading Albertson, Cranston and Fox (2009) and Oporowski and Zhao works on proving the Albertson's conjecture for $7 \leq n \leq 12$ and $n = 6$. It is also stated that the conjecture for $n = 5$ is equivalent to the Four Color Theorem. However this fact seems to be directly ignored, as being taken for granted by Apple and Haken's proof.

Am I missing something as to why can't the $n=5$ be proved formally as the other cases are?

Comment: 4 color false implies exists planar graph requiring 5 colors. Since this graph (being planar) has crossing number zero, it contradicts Albertson which says the smallest crossing number should be achieved by K5.